# Set different PHP UID for Apache VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, php, virtualhost, users, uid

I have many VirtualHosts for different users. How can I set UID for PHP process per VirtualHosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a Linux distribution then you can probably use [suPHP](http://www.suphp.org/Home.html). suPHP allows you to run php scripts with the UID/GID of the php file that is being processed.

You will have to ensure that each of your vhosts has a their own UID/GID.

Answer (score 1):

You could run the php scripts as if they were a CGI and use SuexecUserGroup from mod_suexec to specify which user to run the script as.